Hint for Exercise 3.4(i) in Rotman's Algebraic Topology?
Exercise 3.4(i): Let $\sigma: \Delta^2 \to X$ be continuous, where $\Delta^2 = [e_0, e_1, e_2]$. Define $\epsilon_0: I \to \Delta^2$ as the affine map with $\epsilon_0(0) = e_1$ and $\epsilon_0(1) = e_2$; similarly, define $\epsilon_1$ by $\epsilon_1(0) = e_0$ and $\epsilon_1(1) = e_2$, and define $\epsilon_2$ by $\epsilon_2(0) = e_0$ and $\epsilon_2(1) = e_1$. Finally, define $\sigma_i = \sigma \circ \epsilon_i$ for $i = 0, 1, 2$.
(i). Prove that $(\sigma_0 * \sigma_1^{-1}) * \sigma_2$ is nullhomotopic rel $\overset{*}{I}$ (Hint: Theorem 1.6).
Theorem 1.6:
Let $S^n \to Y$ be a continuous map into some space $Y$. The following conditions are equivalent:

$f$ is nullhomotopic;
$f$ can be extended to a continuous map $D^{n + 1} \to Y$;
if $x_0 \in S^n$ and $k: S^n \to Y$ is the constant map at $f(x_0)$, then there is a homotopy $F: f \simeq k$ with $F(x_0, t) = f(x_0)$ for all $t \in I$.

What I've tried:
I understand that I have to use the fact that $S^1 \cong \overset{*}{\Delta^2}$ and $D^2 \cong \Delta^2$. Let $\tau = (\sigma_0 * \sigma_1^{-1}) * \sigma_2$. Since $\tau$ is constant on the fibers of $\pi: I \to S^1$ (where $\pi$ is the natural quotient map), there is an induced map $\tau': S^1 \to X$ with $\tau = \tau' \circ \pi$. In the spirit of Theorem 1.6, if $\tau'$ can be extended to a continuous map from $D^2$ to $X$, then $\tau'$ will be nullhomotopic, so that $\tau$ is nullhomotopic. Let $h: D^2 \to \Delta^2$ be a homeomorphism. My intuition tells me that $\sigma \circ h$ is a continuous extension of $\tau'$, however, I have been very stuck on how to prove this. Is this even the right approach?
Thank you for any help.

Before we get fancy, this is just the boundary loop of a triangle, and if you visually understand that a (solid) triangle is contractible, you can see that, of course, this loop is nullhomotopic. Using the affine simplex model $\Delta^2$ for a triangle, an explicit contracting homotopy is easy to write down by doing convex combinations of a generic point $p$ with your chosen vertex; here, our loop is based at $e_1$, so we ought to contract down to $e_1$, and $p_s:=s\cdot e_1+(1-s)\cdot p$ will be a path $p\to e_1$ that we define a homotopy $\Delta^2\times I\to\Delta^2$ between $\mathrm{Id}$ and $e_1$. Explicitly, $H((t_0,t_1,t_2),s):=((1-s)t_0,1-(1-s)(t_0+t_2),(1-s)t_2)$ is this map, which is continuous and well-defined, and we see $H(-,0)$ is the identity since $t_0+t_1+t_2\equiv1$ on the simplex and $H(-,1)$ is the constant map to $e_1=(0,1,0)$; moreover, $H(e_1,s)=H((0,1,0),s)=e_1$ for all $s$, so it is a strong contraction.
Then for any given loop $\gamma$ based at $e_1$, $\Gamma(t,s):=H(\gamma(t),s)$ will be a homotopy $\gamma\simeq e_1$ relative to the endpoints (since $H(e_1,s)\equiv e_1$). Now, going one step further, if we have a map $\sigma:\Delta^2\to X$ then $(t,s)\mapsto\sigma(\Gamma(t,s))$ will be a nullhomotopy of $\tau=\sigma\circ\gamma$ relative to the endpoints. The map $\sigma$ and space $X$ are totally arbitrary, the only important detail is that $\Delta^2$ contracts onto $e_1$.
Your idea by comparing with $D^2$ and $S^1$ is fair game, but you seem to be observing $D^2$ is contractible and arguing from there when you could have just argued that $\Delta^2$ is contractible. However, if you already know $D^2\cong\Delta^2$, it should be clear to you that (strong) contractibility is a homeomorphism invariant and therefore that $\Delta^2$ is (abstractly) contractible. Theorem $1.6$ is harder than, but conceptually similar to, the theorem that $\Delta^2$ is contractible.
You've essentially run into a respeeding problem, as well. $\sigma\circ h$ is continuous, so the only question is whether or not $\sigma\circ h|_{S^1}=\tau'$. That is true iff. it is true when we precompose by $\pi$; now you have to wonder whether $\tau=\sigma\circ h\pi$. For this to work in generality, you'd need $h\pi=\gamma=(\sigma_0\ast\sigma_1^{-1})\ast\sigma_2$, but this is unlikely to be true. However, I am almost certain they are just re-speedings of one another, meaning there is an increasing homeomorphism $\alpha:I\cong I$ such that $h\pi=\gamma\alpha$, so that, "morally", they describe the same loop. Loops which are respeedings of one another are always homotopic, which you can see by considering the homotopy $(t,s)\mapsto\gamma(st+(1-s)\alpha(t))$.
